# Not able to add SASS/SCSS to Reactjs project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

I am trying to add sass/scss to Reactjs project following 
this tutorial: https://medium.com/@Connorelsea/using-sass-with-create-react-app-7125d6913760

I installed sass loaders but when I run command `npm run eject` in terminal it says that `Command not found`. I have commited and pushed all changes to my git repository but still not able to run it.

In my package.json have this lines:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "react-svg-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3"
  }
```

And in webpack.config.js:

```
{
   test: /\.sass$/,
   include: paths.appSrc,
   loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
}
```

When I run `npm start` without `npm run eject` have error in `webpack.config.js`

```
ReferenceError: paths is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rules for 'sass or scss' files should look like:

```
{
  test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
  loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
}
```

Comment: yes, I should just have removed `include` it was not same path as in my app :/ Thank you for answer.